# Designer Workflow - The values provided for the root activity's arguments did not satisfy the root activity's requirements

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

We have a 2013 workflow which I edited last week, but since then, the workflow is terminated right away upon start with this message:

> RequestorId: c93c7195-35a5-d89b-0000-000000000000. Details: The values
>   provided for the root activity's arguments did not satisfy the root
>   activity's requirements: 'DynamicActivity': Expected an input
>   parameter value of type 'System.String' for parameter named 'ItemId'.
>   Parameter name: rootArgumentValues

What is triggering this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause**

My first thought was some odd line in the XAML, so I opened it to see that one of my variables, `ItemId` as stated in the error, is used in the XAML syntax. Therefore, this variable name can't be used and causes the error above.

**Solution**

I've renamed the variable to `ItemGUID` in SharePoint Designer and the workflow now runs fine.